# Input Pins having voltages (5V)

Tags: microcontroller, c, input

I am currently working on a microcontroller based system, the issue i am facing is that my inputs pins 40 and 39 of atmega32 are somehow getting internally high, Pin40 shows 2.5 volts and Pin39 shows 5v on my voltmeter. As far as I understand the pins are getting high due to code but I have cross checked several times but still cant figure out the issue with my code. 
I am including the circuit diagram and code as well. Can any one please point out how my input pins are showing voltages.
 [image: Atmega32 circuit with lcd interfaced]

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL // 16 MHz clock speed
#endif

#define D0 eS_PORTD0
#define D1 eS_PORTD1
#define D2 eS_PORTD2
#define D3 eS_PORTD3
#define D4 eS_PORTD4
#define D5 eS_PORTD5
#define D6 eS_PORTD6
#define D7 eS_PORTD7
#define RS eS_PORTC6
#define EN eS_PORTC7

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "lcd.h"

void Init_ADC(void)
{
ADMUX|=(1<<REFS0);
ADMUX&=~((1<<REFS1)|(1<<MUX0)|(1<<MUX1)|(1<<MUX2)|(1<<MUX3)|(1<<MUX4));
// SELECTING CHANNEL0
ADCSRA|=(1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS0);
// NORMAL CONVERSION WITHOUT INTERRUPT
ADCSRA&=~((1<<ADSC)|(1<<ADATE)|(1<<ADIF)|(1<<ADIE)|(1<<ADPS1));
// CLOCK/32 SPEED
}
unsigned int Read_ADC(uint8_t ch)
{
ADMUX&=0b11111000;
ch=ch&0b00000111;
ADMUX|=ch;
//Start Single Conversion

ADCSRA|= (1<<ADSC);
// Wait for conversion to complete
while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC));

// Clear ADIF by writing one to it
//ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF);

return(ADCW);
}


void Wait()
{
uint8_t i;
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
_delay_loop_2(0);
}

int main(void)
{
int v,v1,v2,vref;
vref = 409;
DDRD = 0xFF; 
DDRB = 0xFF; 
DDRC = 0xFF;

Init_ADC();
Lcd8_Init();

while(1)
{
    v2 = Read_ADC(1);
    if(v2>=900)
    {
        Lcd8_Set_Cursor(1,1);
        vref = Read_ADC(0);
        Lcd8_Write_String(" Ref. Set");
        _delay_ms(2000);
        Lcd8_Clear();

    }
    else
    {
        Lcd8_Set_Cursor(1,1);

        v1=Read_ADC(0);

        if(v1>=1.05*vref)
        {
            v=0x01;
            Lcd8_Write_String(" HIGH");
        }
        else if(v1<=0.95*vref)
        {
            v=0x01;
            Lcd8_Write_String(" LOW");
        }
        else
        {
            v=0x00;
            Lcd8_Write_String(" OK");
        }
        PORTB=v;
        //Wait();
        _delay_ms(2000);
        Lcd8_Clear();
    }
}
```

}

Thnks everyone in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Setting PORTxn will enable the pullup on the associated input. Reset it in order to disable the pullup.

Comment: Can u please help me with code, I am not good at C !!

Comment: Using port B pin 0 as an example: PORTB &= ~(1<<0); DDRB &= ~(1<<0); leaves the pin floating. PORTB |= (1<<0); DDRB &= ~(1<<0); pulls the pin up with an internal 10k resistor. PORTB &= ~(1<<0); DDRB |= (1<<0); drives the pin low. PORTB |= (1<<0); DDRB |= (1<<0); drives the pin high.